# elasticsearch query string containing /

Tags: elasticsearch

I am trying to hit a query in elastic search. This is working fine except for '/' present in the search. the query is as shown below

```
GET styling_rules/product_line_filters/_search
{
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
      "query": {
        "query_string" : {
            "query" : "boyfriend / boxy"
        }
    },
      "filter": {
        "term": {
          "product_line_name": "women_blazers"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

here in elasticsearch '/' is already present but with the query it is showing error. how to handle these situtation. Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you provide a sample document which should be matched against your query!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to escape that character. See here the full list of characters to be escaped in query_string: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-query-string-query.html#_reserved_characters