# How to query in elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I am working on elastic search to fetch the record which contain string **"bond"**

```
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "name": "Bond"
    }
  }
}
```

but I am getting empty array as a output. Though multiple records are present containing string "bold" , but i am getting empty hits. (hits:[])

**How to solve this issue?**

I am using same query for another index and its working but for index named as "all_colleges", its not working.
Its only returning the record when string is perfect match. i.e. "Bond" == "Bond"

Comment: Does this answer your question? [elasticsearch query string containing /](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43680189/elasticsearch-query-string-containing)

Comment: nope,  @KennetsuRinn

Comment: This [reference](https://pranavprakash.net/2017/09/13/case-insensitive-exact-match-search-in-elasticsearch/) may be helpful for you. Otherwise please show us the mappings of your ES.

Comment: @AdityaSonawane this is possible by allowing some fuzziness, you can check [my answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71109943/4604579)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try with [fuzziness](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.17/query-dsl-match-query.html#query-dsl-match-query-fuzziness):

```
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "name": {
         "query": "Bond",
         "fuzziness": "AUTO"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: its giving following output   `{
  "took" : 1,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 1,
    "successful" : 1,
    "skipped" : 0,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : {
      "value" : 0,
      "relation" : "eq"
    },
    "max_score" : null,
    "hits" : [ ]
  }
}`

Comment: Can you share the mapping of the `name` field?

Comment: i dont have much knowledge, is there any way i can share my screen and you can help me to solve this issue

Comment: `{
  "properties": {
    "country": {
      "type": "keyword"
    },
    "course_global_rank": {
      "type": "long"
    },
    "course_name": {
      "type": "keyword"
    },
    "global_rank": {
      "type": "long"
    },
    "name": {
      "type": "keyword"
    },
    "sub_course": {
      "type": "keyword"
    },
    "sub_course_global_rank": {
      "type": "long"
    }
  }
}`

Comment: Ok, I see the problem, your name field is of type keyword (value is not analyzed), so the match query with fuzziness won't work here. You should change it to `text` instead

Comment: thanks a lot @Val, it solved the issue

Answer (score 0):

Actually there is many parameters you can add to get the results that you want in elastic search. Please check this link https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-match-query.html

You can try this one

```
{
    "query": {
        "match": {
            "name": {
                "query": "Bond",
                "fuzziness": "AUTO"
             }
         }
     }
}
```

`